# В консоли у стэк вызова отображается ссылка на фрагмент после вебпака, а не исходный код

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

У нас есть такой варнинг в консоли:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `xs` supplied to `ForwardRef(Grid)`, expected one of type [number, boolean].
    at Grid (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39849:87)
    at StartPage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25794:72)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:97274:5)
    at InnerThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47038:70)
    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46740:5)
    at ThemeProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47058:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:97207:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:96016:5)
    at div
    at App
```

Нас ведет на `bundle.js:39849:87`, то есть на код после вебпака, я же хочу увидеть реальный код, в котором произошла проблема. Я запускаю сборку в режиме разработки `npm run start`.
Предполагаю, что проблема в sourceMap, их не генерирует, но как решить проблему - не знаю.

package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.6.0",
        "@mui/material": "^5.6.0",
        "@syncfusion/ej2-react-charts": "^20.1.47",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^0.26.1",
        "qs": "^6.10.3",
        "react": "^18.0.0",
        "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
        "react-scroll": "^1.8.7",
        "react-svg-radar-chart": "^1.3.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "18.7.15",
        "@types/react": "18.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.0.0",
        "eslint": "8.11.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0",
        "typescript": "4.8.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ],
        "rules": {
            "default-case": 0
        }
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы пробовали активировать sourceMap через package.json?

Comment: У вас какая сборка, cra?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, к сожалению я не знаю за CRA, но похоже на обычный create-react-app. Через package это `"start": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true\" && react-scripts start",`?

Comment: Вроде да. Так должно работать. Хотя я думаю если у вас обычный CRA, то из коробки должен поддержать sourceMap.

Comment: Ну... данный код ничем не помог, я его даже изначально пытался в `.env` вставлять.